# Can not merge opencv static .lib's into one .lib

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, lib, unresolved-external

As you might know, when you compile OpenCV statically, it produces a significant amount of `.lib` files and now I need to merge them all into one `.lib` file. For that I use next command:

`lib.exe /OUT:opencv_all.lib IlmImf.lib ittnotify.lib libjasper.lib libjpeg-turbo.lib libpng.lib libprotobuf.lib libtiff.lib opencv_calib3d411.lib opencv_core411.lib opencv_dnn411.lib opencv_highgui411.lib opencv_imgcodecs411.lib opencv_imgproc411.lib opencv_video411.lib opencv_videoio411.lib quirc.lib zlib.lib`

But when I use my `.lib` file the code doesn't work, I have a huge pile of `Unresolved external symbol` errors. The thing that I'm having `Unresolved external symbol` error for every single use of this library. Please advice what am I missing here

Comment: "As you might know...." -- not if you build `opencv_world`. Run CMake with `-DBUILD_opencv_world=ON` instead of re-inventing the wheel ;)

Comment: Hello @DanMašek! Thank you for your response! I already tried that but I still have the same outcome - a pile of `Unresolved external symbol` errors